# How to get the first and last row of data per user

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to write a query to select only the first and last record for each user.

[image: Employee Data]

Basically I want to:

```
SELECT * FROM EmpData WHERE ClockNo is DISTINCT AND only the first and last record
is displayed like in the picture. N.B it's color-coded per user
```

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpData](
[ClockNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Department] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ClockPoint] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Time] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple approaches to doing this.  But having the date/time values are in two columns makes this a hard problem.  So, most methods involve date manipulations -- which can be quite database dependent.

Here is a method that requires no date/time manipulations.  And, it should perform pretty well on most databases with the appropriate indexes:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.clockno = t.clockno and
                        (t2.date > t.date or
                         t2.date = t.date and t2.time > t.time
                        )
                  ) or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.clockno = t.clockno and
                        (t2.date < t.date or
                         t2.date = t.date and t2.time < t.time
                        )
                  ) ;
```

If you want the data *per day*, then I would go for:

```
select t.*
from t join
     (select clockno, date, min(time) as mint, max(time) as maxt
      from t
      group by clockno, date
     ) tt
     on tt.clockno = t.clockno and tt.date = t.date and
        t.time in (tt.mint, tt.maxt);
```

Comment: Too bad the date and time fields are varchar.

Comment: to_date(time,'hh24miss') and to_date(date,'YYYYMMDD') should solve that

Comment: It's working by giving 2 lines of data per user but when checking at the time it doesn't take the first recorded time. How do I check against the time column. Note that it's nvarchar

Comment: @JohnaneUmslana . . . You need to convert the time to an integer or numeric.

Comment: What if the days lapses and the start time is 210000 and end time is the next day 050000?